# Using file templates in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm quite confused when it comes to file templates in IntelliJ. Basically, when I right click anything and hover my mouse over to New, I can see the usual file templates like Java Class, HTML File and so on. I downloaded Scala plugin and I can see Scala templates (Scala Class, Scala Object, etc.) if I go to Edit File Templates, but I can't actually use/see them in the New menu. Is there a way to modify what I see in the New menu? I'd like to be able to create Scala classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Menus and Toolbars

There you will see many type of menus. You need edit the menu you want the files to be displayed. Most Probably "Project View Popup Menu".

[image: Added Show Bytes to Menu]

Click on "Add After" button on right. There you choose the file form plug-ins or other category to be displayed.

[image]

I added "Show Bytecode" to meny well it does not make sense here. You can add files from scala plugin like that.
[image]

> You can restore to Defaults if you mess up easily by clicking on
>   "Restore All Defaults" button.